# Cloud service for my own music files with offline sync?

Tags: offline, music, cloud-service

I have  a windows PC , a Mac (el capitan ) and an android lollipop device ,
My problem is pretty simple , I have around 3 gigs of music , I keep adding a little once in a while , 
I want a cloud service similar to Google drive (it need or need not include a music streaming service like apple music )

I want offline sync ie whatever changes I make to be reflected in the cloud and my offline copy

Google drive works perfectly for pc and mac (both platform native desktop apps)..

When I go to mobile the problem startes , google drive for android does not have a offline folder (you can download certain items offline but it aint the same )

and moreover my music apps cant detect and play those files .

So please suggest some software for this..

to 
Upload my songs online
keep a local copy in sync on all platforms , pc ,mac , android and preferrably ios too

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-us/). Music stored in OneDrive can be automatically played through Groove, Microsoft's music platform available on the web or as an app. I use it for many of my music needs and I don't really have any issues with it.

Comment: Not relevant anymore, as Groove was shut down

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can't just use one tool. You already have *one* software that does what you want to do on PC and OS X. Its useful to have another way of solving the problem. Google has a a music service called google play music, and it can be kept in sync with a local repository of music. [Point google play music manager at the folder your music is in](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1075570?hl=en), and it handles conversion and streaming.

It'll also play local files, and cache as needed, and google music manager makes sure you can access it remotely. Works really well for me.

I've something like 100gb of music, so size and number of tracks shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: :( Problem is play music is unavailable where I live .

Comment: @SainathS.R, google account country is changeable like a charm. Believe me and unleash the magic:)

Answer (score 0):

Try [Mega](https://mega.nz/) or Dropbox. Their Android apps have offline folder.